# I want to use HTML to style and format my viz. description in Public

Tags: tableau-api

Is there any way to format a description of a Tableau Public visualisation? I see some of the staff picks have italics, but cannot figure it out. Must be missing something simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think this is possible. Can you post a link to a viz with formatting?

Comment: https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/hawk-migration or others in the gallery. I think they have special CSS set up for them. :/

Comment: Agreed...it must be the hand-picked viz's